# How do I create a new list of tuples?

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have this homework problem, and I'm new to python.  I have this list of tuples:

[('the, this is me', 'the night'), ('the night', 'me'), ('me', 'the store')]

My code doesn't work when I'm trying to write to target_bigrams with only the tuples that have "the" in position [0].  Please help.

```
target_bigrams = ()
bigrams_length = len(bigrams)
  
for i in range(bigrams_length):   
    if i[0] == target_word:
        target_bigrams.append(i[0])
```

​

Comment: `tuple`s are immutables. One cannot `append`, `remove`, or `modify` them. So `target_bigrams.append(i[0])` would fail since `target_bigrams`is tuple.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need;

```
bigrams = [('the, this is me', 'the night'), ('the night', 'me'), ('me', 'the store')]
target_word = 'the'

target_bigrams = []
bigrams_length = len(bigrams)
  
for i in range(bigrams_length):   
    if bigrams[i][0].startswith(target_word):
        target_bigrams.append(bigrams[i][0])
```

Answer (score -1):

The question is not clear, but i believe that you want to separate the tuples which has "the" in the first position.
If that is the case, here is the sample code for your reference

```
lst = [('the, this is me', 'the night'), ('the night', 'me'), ('me', 'the store'), ('the', 'the store'),("the","How are you")]

target_list = []
target_word = "the"
for i in range(len(lst)):
    if target_word == lst[i][0]:
        target_list.append(lst[i])

for i in target_list:
    print(i)

Output:
('the', 'the store')
('the', 'How are you')
```

Comment: Thank you for trying to answer my question. I realized I made a mistake with the tuples.  They should be only 2 words at a time so I had to go back and create the new tuples.  It was my first time asking a question and now I realize there needs to be a complete and clear question.